# SwiftUI - AVPlayerViewController Full Screen on tvOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayerviewcontroller

I am able to present an `AVPlayerViewController` from SwiftUI but there is some padding around the video and I would like for it to be full-screen.

From the SwiftUI portion there is the following:

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(topicsArray) { topic in
                Section(header: Text(topic.title)) {
                    ForEach(0..<topic.shows.count) { index in
                        NavigationLink(destination: PlayerView(showID: topic.shows[index])) {
                            ShowCell(showID: topic.shows[index])
                        }
                        .navigationBarTitle("")
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        .padding()
    }.onAppear(perform: initialDataLoad)
}
```

The code being called from the `NavigationLink` that shows the player is:

```
    struct PlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
       var showID:Int

       func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
           let pv = PlayerViewController()
           pv.showID = showID
           return pv
       }

       func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {

       }
   }

class PlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {
    var showID:Int! {
        didSet {
            setup()
        }
    }
    private var videoLaunch:VideoLaunch!

    private func setup() {
        videoLaunch = VideoLaunch(showID: showID,
                                  season: nil,
                                  episodeID: nil,
                                  selectedIndex: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0),
                                  showType: .single,
                                  dataStructure: topics as Any,
                                  screenType: .live)

        playVideo()
    }

    private func playVideo() {
        guard let videoURL = self.videoLaunch.getMediaURL() else {print("Problem getting media URL");return}
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        self.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        self.player?.play()
    }
```

I have tried setting the bounds and using the `modalpresentationstyle` for fullscreen, but none have had any impact. There is still what looks like a 10 point border around the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by inserting the following within the `PlayerViewController` class.

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       self.view.bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    }
```